# Is a mac machine required to compile .NET MAUI Libraries that have UIKit specific code in the Platform folder?

Tags: macos, cross-platform, visual-studio-mac

On Microsoft's [Pair to Mac page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/pair-to-mac), it indicates that a "*network connection to a Mac build host and uses the build tools on that machine to compile and sign the iOS app.*"
The thing is, I'm not compiling an app, rather, I'm building cross-platform MAUI libraries, packaging them into nugets for an app to use.

So far I've packaged these nugets with a 'Pair to Mac' link, and without the link. What I've found is that I'm still able to use the specific iOS functionality from the Platform folder regardless if the Pairing is done or not.

Does anyone know if I need a physical mac (Pair with connection) to build cross-platform MAUI libraries? So far I'm not seeing the need for a physical mac to simply build cross-platform libraries.